# How would I calculate age of this tricycle

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, tricycle

I just purchased a Miami sun tricycle used and in very bad shape with rust. I'm starting restore process and luckily rust has not gotten to far into frame. I found a number under seat mount on bike frame but only 5 digits and all I've read said s/n were 6-12 characters [

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I see cottered cranks, suggesting the bike is 1970's at the latest, and could be anything up to 70 years older than that.

Clearly your bike has had at least one repaint too - I'd guess the red is an original colour and the blue is brush-painted on.

The "Miami Bicycle & Supply Co" seems to have first filed accounts in 1971, according to https://www.corporationwiki.com/Florida/Miami/miami-bicycle-supply-co-inc-3439977.aspx  and had some trademarks through the 1990's.  The same three owners are listed, at https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_fl/382779

The brand "Sun Bicycle" still exists but likely is unrelated to the company that make your trike.   Curiously, they still have a 20" trike at https://sun.bike/products/traditional-20-unisex-12863 and I can see a similar saddle-support rod to your ride.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response Criggie. Wow that is the body style almost exactly . I didn't realize it could be that old. That's insane. I bought that. Bought it for $40. It wasn't pretty bad shape though. I found some tires that match films exactly to what was originally on there in their brand. New bearings were a little difficult to find but I did end up finding them just cuz nobody sells the HW 13B's around me.While sanding I believe it's been painted 3 times. Blue is the newest paint( horrible paint job) then red and I also came across white as well. I contacted sun bicycles

Comment: And they confirmed they are the new owners of Miami Sun but could not give me any details due to that being built before their buying out of Miami Sun